# How i can Replace Only first Result in SQL Function

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, string, sql-update

I will ask about SQL replacement function.

I need to your bits of help. In Wordpress DB, I must change a little part. I want to replace first result only in a column. I will explain by giving an example,

My string is = "Hello **XXX** tomorrow we **XXX** will meeting in **XXX** Dubai, Do you want join us **XXX** ? "

My result must be like this=  "Hello **MMM** tomorrow we **XXX** will meeting in **XXX** Dubai, Do you want join us **XXX** ? "

in this example, we putted MMM to first result of XXX . How i can do it ?

I tried below this code but, it replaced every XXX to MMM;

```
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE ( comment_content, 'XXX', 'MMM' ) WHERE `comment_ID`=334 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL < 8.0, where `regexp_replace()` and the-like are not supported, you can use string functions:

```
update wp_comments
set comment_content = concat(
    substr(comment_content, 1, locate('XXX', comment_content) - 1),
    'MMM',
    substr(comment_content, locate('XXX', comment_content) + 3)
) 
where comment_id = 334 and locate('XXX', comment_content) > 0
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d76c0c382f5b56b2d006d1ccb61d38bb)**:

```
comment_id | comment_content                                                               
---------: | :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       334 | Hello MMM tomorrow we XXX will meeting in XXX Dubai, Do you want join us XXX ?
```

Answer (score 1):

[`regexp_replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) can do what you want.  It takes an optional argument which is the occurrence to replace:

```
UPDATE wp_comments
    SET comment_content = REGEXP_REPLACE( comment_content, 'XXX', 'MMM', 1, 1 )
    WHERE comment_ID = 334
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: when I use it , it is getting error 

REGEXP_REPLACE is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: @AhmetKaya . . . As shown in the documentation, `REGEXP_REPLACE()` is a MySQL function.