# How i can use REGEXP_REPLACE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I asked a question but answer is not usable on my computer.

[How i can Replace Only first Result in SQL Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159171/how-i-can-replace-only-first-result-in-sql-function)

here, the result is using `REGEXP_REPLACE` function but I cant use it on SSMS 18

it is getting this error;

> REGEXP_REPLACE is not a recognized built-in function name

How I can use this function?

Comment: SSMS is SQL server and the linked stackoverflow post is MySQL?

Comment: You should ask a question that is complete in itself, with sample data and desired results.  An appropriate database tag also helps.

Comment: dear Gordon Linoff, you answered my question but I cant use  REGEXP_REPLACE function ?

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are *completely* different RDBMS, functions that are in one won't be in another (either by name or at all). SQL Server has no native support for REGEX. if you *do* need the functionality, you will need to look at implementing CLR functions.

Comment: @AhmetKaya: since your other question was responded, you might want to consider deleting this one.

Comment: But in the other question, the OP told people they were using a different RDBMS, @GMB . They misinformed the users that have taken the tiem to answer them.

Comment: @Larnu: yes indeed. But since they accepted an answer on the other question (after posting this question !), I tend to suspect that they are actually using MySQL... But maybe not, who knows?

Comment: *"REGEXP_REPLACE is not a recognized built-in function name"* Is a SQL server error, @GMB .

Comment: @Larnu: ah, yes, my bad, you are right. So they might be looking for a cross-database solution (which is not likely to exists)...?